# I have trouble displaying my api data on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building a react app that fetches a random food data from spoonacular.com. Im trying to display the title name of the food on the page but it doesn't show up and also why does it keep fetching a bunch of different data as shown in the picture of the console.log even though I specified the number of data to fetch as 1 in the URL

This is my Home.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Recipe from "../components/Recipes";

const URL = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=${APIKey}&number=1`;

function Home() {
  const [food, setFood] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(URL)
      .then(function (response) {
        setFood(response.data);
        console.log(food);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  }, [food]);

  return (
    <main>
      <Recipe recipeList={food} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

and this is my Recipe.js component

```
import React from "react";

function Recipe({ recipeList }) {
  return (
    <div className="recipeCard">
      <h1>{recipeList.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Recipe;
```

and this is the picture of the console when I log the results fetched from the API (they're all different food datas but I only wanted to fetch 1 food data and display it on the page)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you get 1 random recipe, but `useEffect` works every time you update the `food` state, so you have an infinite loop. Just remove `food` from `useEffect` dependency. It's also better to check if recipeList exists so you don't get a missing title error
This should work as expected:
Home.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Recipe from "../components/Recipes";

const URL = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=${APIKey}&number=1`;

function Home() {
  const [food, setFood] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(URL)
      .then(function (response) {
        setFood(response.data);
        console.log(food);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      <Recipe recipeList={food} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Recipe.js:

```
import React from "react";

function Recipe({ recipeList }) {

  if(!recipeList) return <></>
  return (
    <div className="recipeCard">
      <h1>{recipeList?.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Recipe;
```

Comment: But idk why the title of the data isn’t displaying on the page…is something in my code written wrong?

Comment: Try changing the initial state from {} to null and in the child component put a check before return " if(!recipeList) return <></> " . Since you can get an error that the title does not exist, if suddenly the component is rendered before receiving the response

Comment: i made changes to my answer

Comment: I changed my code to yours to test it out and for some reason the title still doesn't show on the page